# ¿Como imprimo los strings de un map dado a una variable definida?

Tags: java, string, variables, estructuras-de-datos, map

Hola tengo una pregunta y es que quiero imprimir los Strings de un Map pero dado a con una key, es decir tengo una lista de Strings y otra lista de Integer, se llenan los datos normal pero luego yo en mi programa busco el numero mayor de la lista de los Integer y dado a ese numero mayor quiero imprimir solo los Strings que tengan ese numero de Integer.

Si no me hice entender muy bien aqui el problema principal: https://vjudge.net/contest/455620#problem/G

aqui dejo mi codigo:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class concantenar {

    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static int number;
    static String web;
    static int mayor = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Map<String, Integer> nombreMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        int cases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                String textos = br.readLine();
                String[] parts = textos.split(" ");
                web = parts[0];
                number = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

                nombreMap.put(web, number);
            }

            if (number > mayor) {
                mayor = number;
            }
            
            for (Entry<String, Integer> keyValue : nombreMap.entrySet()) {
                if (keyValue.getValue() >= mayor) {
                    System.out.println(keyValue.getValue());
                }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Si me ayudan estaria genial y estaria agradecido :D

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener las Key - Value de un Map tenes que usar Entry, habían otros para casos específicos pero no los recuerdo.

Donde esta el mensaje que queres imprimir los de mayor debes usar esto:

```
for (Entry<String, Integer> keyValue : nombreMap.entrySet()) {
    if (keyValue.getValue() == mayor) {
        System.out.println(keyValue.getKey());
    }
 }
```

**Edit:**
Además que la comprobación de si es el numero es mayor al numero mayor, debe ir adentro del segundo bucle for.

Entonces para imprimir las keys de un map usas `keyValue.getKey()` y para los value `keyValue.getValue()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Map<String, Integer> nombreMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    int cases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            String textos = br.readLine();
            String[] parts = textos.split(" ");
            web = parts[0];
            
            number = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

            if (number > mayor) {
                mayor = number;
                //System.out.println("El numero mayor es: " + mayor);
            }
            
            nombreMap.put(web, number);
        }
        
        for (Entry<String, Integer> keyValue : nombreMap.entrySet()) {
            if (keyValue.getValue() == mayor) {
                System.out.println(keyValue.getKey());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

La entrada es:

```
5
www.youtube.com 1
www.google.com 2
www.google.com.hk 3
www.alibaba.com 10
www.taobao.com 5
www.bad.com 10
www.good.com 7
www.fudan.edu.cn 8
www.univercity.edu.cn 9
acn.univercity.edu.cn 10
```

La salida es:

```
www.alibaba.com
acn.univercity.edu.cn
www.bad.com
```

Comment: Hola, mira cuando en el mapara en la lista Integer se pasan 10 datos, de estos casos se busca el mayor, es decir "(cada cuanto se considera numero mayor)" cuando se pasan cada 10 datos se buscan entre ellos el mayor.  Otra cosita y es el codigo que me pasaste me muestra son los numeros pero quiero es el String, como podria arreglar eso?, te coloque la imagen en la publicacion

Comment: @asdfg Edite mi respuesta, mala mía, me equivoque en la escritura del código, te puse ``keyValue.getValue``, y era ``keyValue.getKey()`` para los string, y la comprobación va adentro del segundo bucle ``for``, porque así como estaba, siempre tomaba el ultimo valor y no el numero mas alto.

Comment: Bro ya me sirve muchas gracias.